# Merge local files than pushing to git

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, local-files

So, I have a cloned repo on my machine.(folder A). And I have another folder in which my files are updated, but it is not a git repo.(folder B). I would like to merge all files and folders from folder B with folder A (which is my cloned repo).
The rest is easy, just `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.
Thanks!

Comment: what do you intend to ask ??

Comment: Well, I think it is obvious. I would like to know how to merge the files from folder B (which is not a repo) with the files from folder A(my cloned repo).

Comment: `git checkout -b folder-b; cp ../folderB/* .; git add .; git commit; git checkout master; git merge folder-b` or something like that?

Comment: Well, that could work, but could you tell me in which folder do I need to execute every command? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this

```
aa=/path/to/folder-a
bb=/path/to/folder-b

cd $aa
git rm -qr .
cp -r $bb/. .
git add -A
git commit
git push
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/scripts/jekyll-publish.sh)